# How can I distribute the bounty of a question among multiple answer givers

Tags: discussion, bounty

I am in a situation where I have raised a Question and subsequently offered a bounty over the question. The bounty expires soon.

There were three (3) answers and two (2) answers were good answers from 2 different perspective but none of them have pointed to the real solution.

Now, I have got the actual solution from an external source (outside stackoverflow.com) and I have added an Answer for that question for the benefit of the entire stackoverflow.com community and the future readers.

My question is, how can I distribute the bounty of the question among multiple answer givers?

Comment: You can't. Start a new bounty to reward the other answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't.  You have to pick one answer.